# Curve Fit with logarithmic Regression in Python

Tags: machine-learning, python, nonlinear-regression, logarithm, scipy

I need to find a model which best fits my data. It looks like this:

[image]

So I thought about logarithmic regression.

But when I try to make a simple fit in python I get the following result:

[image]

My code for now looks like this:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from pylab import rcParams
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 20,10

plt.close('all')

# read the data
with open('car-2015-10-16-12-19-23.log.csv','r') as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f,delimiter=',')
    next(reader, None)
    data=np.array([tuple(row[0:]+row[:1]) for row in reader],dtype=None)

# print(mc.report_memory())   

# to test some time-windows
#data = data[500:1500]

# delete Fuel Status because sometimes there is NODATA or garbage
data = np.delete(data,np.s_[::5],1)

# convert last index to microseconds
for dt in data:
    ms = datetime.strptime(dt[-1], '%H:%M:%S.%f')
    dt[-1] = ms.microsecond + ms.second * 1000000 + ms.minute * 60 * 1000000 + ms.hour *3600 * 1000000
    dt[1] = float(dt[1]) * 1.60934

# font style
labelfont = {
        'family' : 'sans-serif',  # (cursive, fantasy, monospace, serif)
        'color'  : 'black',       # html hex or colour name
        'weight' : 'normal',      # (normal, bold, bolder, lighter)
        'size'   : 36,            # default value:12
        }

titlefont = {
        'family' : 'serif',
        'color'  : 'black',
        'weight' : 'bold',
        'size'   : 40,
        }

# delete garbage
data = np.delete(data, 0, 0)
data = np.delete(data, 0, 0)

# title and labels
plt.title('Throttle - Load Relation', fontdict=titlefont) 
plt.xlabel('Throttle in %', fontdict=labelfont)
plt.ylabel('Load in %', fontdict=labelfont)

# adjust fontsize of ticks
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=30)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize=30)

# return data as float
data = data.astype(float)

# just for regression
xdata = data[:,2]
ydata = data[:,3]

# logarithmic function
def func(x, p1,p2):
  return p1*np.log(x)+p2

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata,p0=(1.0,10.2))

# curve params
p1 = popt[0]
p2 = popt[1]

# plot curve
curvex=np.linspace(15,85,1000)
curvey=func(curvex,p1,p2)
plt.plot(curvex,curvey,'r', linewidth=5)

# plot data
plt.plot(data[:,2],data[:,3],'x',label = 'Xsaved')

plt.show()
```

The point is that both x and y can only be max 100% therefore I decided to try with logarithmic regression.

If you want you can get the data from

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7s23N5eDcceR00yUDZWUC1zWE0/view?usp=sharing

**EDIT:**

To better explain what I'm looking for:

[image]

Where btw. how to start here then?

Comment: What is your question? Looking at your code you may want to use `pandas.read_csv` instead.  It's a lot easier to use than the `csv` module.

Comment: my question is if I could fit the curve more...
I think it's not the best fit or my model is not enough...

Comment: You could try fitting a spline or loess curve. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scatterplot_smoothing

Comment: just tried with polynomial of 4th degree and got better fit. but I'm sceptical if I'm right

Comment: should I filter the data (f.e. after 30% of throttle there are some exceptions) and so get logarithmic function of better fit?

Comment: Your drawn fit (the green curve) makes little sense. Consider where you have the green curve when throttle is below 20 and compare it with the mean at given values there. E.g. look at the data in this [thin strip](http://i.imgur.com/ljdb32j.png) (marked in red), somewhere around throttle=17%. Your green line has the mean way down at 10, possibly lower (i.e. below *all* the data in that region except for the low outliers). The curve there should be somewhere up around the interval I marked in brown -- up around load=15%. Your curve is far below E(Y|X=x) there & also below the conditional median

Comment: @Glen_b: you're right without any doubt. the drawn curve should only be the visualisation of what I'm thinking about. At the moment I got quite good result with 3th or 4th degree polynomial. as the ranges are limited to 100 I want to go on with testing another data-samples if it fits in what I have.

Comment: It looks to me like you might consider splines; natural regression splines might work well  (with knots about every 5% at the left end where there's lots of data and maybe every 10% above x=40-ish); alternatively cubic smoothing splines might work well enough.

Comment: @Glen_b: just read about splines and I agree with you that it will make sense. do you know about good examples with python? I get  enough with R but it will be difficult for me to switch at the moment

Comment: @x4k3p Sorry, I know only a little python

Comment: ok, I think I will start with patsy

Comment: what you are looking (the green lines you drew in the picture) for is a piecewise linear function, why not fit with piecewise linear function? something like [this](http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-for-ecologists-putting-together-a-piecewise-regression/)

Comment: Original question was off-topic in focus on Python, but as the central point seems to be how to model such data, this has survived.

Comment: Wow, isn't it amazing that nobody suggested the user to first use logarithmic and double logarithmic coordinates to actually check whether the function is a power or a logarithm? o_O

Answer (score 4):

(Post edited based on comments - thank you for the corrections)

Your data looks very much like the data I see every day as a biochemist.  I see no reason that your data should look like enzyme reaction curves, but it seems that your data may be modeled well by a fit that works well for enzyme reaction curves, generalized logistic function:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_logistic_function

(Since you appear to be using python, here is a modified form of the generalized logistic, expressed in a form usable for python scripting)

```
def fivepl(x, a, b, c, d, g):

return ( ( (a-d) / ( (1+( (x/c)** b )) **g) ) + d )
```

In this variant of the generalized logistic, here are what the variables represent:

$a$ the lower asymptote

$b$ the Hill coefficient, i.e. the steepness of the slope in the linear portion of the sigmoid

$c$ is related to the value $Y(0)$, and is the inflection point of the curve, i.e. the $x$ value of the middle of the the linear portion of the curve

$d$ the upper asymptote

$g$ asymmetry factor - set to 0.5 initially

Comment: Looks helpful, but it's customary to state the software you are using and not to assume that people use whatever you use. I guess the last  right parenthesis closing `return()`. comes too early. The implication presumably is to reach for some nonlinear least squares function; yours being `curve_fit`.

Comment: I guess you're using Python like the OP. Convention here is to focus on statistics, not code in any particular software.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit late, but this helped me:

instead of `p1*np.log(x)+p2`, try:

```
def func(x, a, b,c):
    return a*np.log2(b+x)+c
```

without the parameter `b`, I get the same problem than you but with it, it fits well.

This may then be used with scipy's curve fit:

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y)
```

And plotted

```
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x, y, label="Original Noised Data")
plt.plot(x, func(x, *popt), 'r-', label="Fitted Curve")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

You can `print popt` to get the values of `a,b,c`.

Comment: Could you expand your answer a little bit more? *Why* do you suggest using such function?

Comment: @Sam What's your source/ref for the model design?

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing which physical process is working in the background.
I would suggest to use two functions which cover different areas of the data.

[image]

My python skills are not sufficient to solve this task nicely, but maybe this is a beginning. 
I fittet your proposed function to two sections of the  data. But (1) I do not know how to blend the functions nicely and (2) if it would be possible to plug this approach in the optimiser as well.

[image]

However, maybe another problem is the distribution of data points. Since you have a lot more data points for the low throttle area the fitting algorithm might weigh this area more (how does python fitting work?).

To prevent this I sliced the data up into 15 slices average those and than fit through 15 data points.

Averaging the slices and tweaking the *model* (by scaling and moving the data, be aware that most of the functions look very nice in the range from 0 to 1, but real data usually *lives* somewhere else.)

```
p1 * np.log( (x-p3)/p4 ) + p2
```

I end up with:

[image]

The green dots are the slice-averages. The parameters are:

```
[18.26324409 -34.75603362  15.80303842   0.10152119]
```

Comment: could anyone help me with my figure. I don't really know why they look so crappy/blurry

Answer (score -2):

To me that looks like a square root function, If you use a regression with the order of 1/2 that might give you a greater correlation.